# Error in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I have the following R code:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(825)
fitControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedvd", number=10, repeats=10)
logitfit1 <- train(y~x+y+z, data=train1, method="logreg", trControl = fitControl, verbose=FALSE)
```

Basically it is building a logistic regression model using 10-fold cross validation on a data set called train1. But I get the following error:

```
Error in names(resamples) <- gsub("^\\.", "", names(resamples)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Why is this?

Comment: Is that really your formula? Do you have `y` as both a response and a predictor? And I think you meant "repeatedcv", not "repeatedvd" for the method.